# How to do a search-and-replace in Opera for textarea context?

Tags: opera, text-editing, find-and-replace

How do I do a search-and-replace in Opera for a textarea's context?  I have a web page with html form and I need to input and edit large text in this form.

Easy example:

1. Stay on this page, scroll it down
2. Find "Your Answer" and a big rectangle area to input text in.
3. Add some large text, e.g.

   This is an example of long long text.
   This is an example of long long text.
   This is an example of long long text.
4. Now My task is: Change all substrings of "This" into "That"; Change all strings of "long long" to "very long". If I use a notepad.exe or any text editor, I can press "Ctrl-G" or call "search-and-replace" dialog from menu. This will show dialog window with fields "Search for" and "Replace with". I can input my task into this window and then editor will do a replaciton in the text.

The input form which I want to edit is not of my site (I can't change the html; but I can install a UserJS). I want to stay in the browser, because this site allow me to do some often-to-use actions (like '{}' or 'Image' button on this site). But if the task is to do replacement in many places, it is hard to do this by hand.

The input form which I want to edit has some nice editing functions, but not the search-and-replace.

My Browser can do only "Search" function on text inside the textarea.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default you cannot do this in Opera.

However, there is a VERY good chance that one of the many extensions will have such a feature. I have not looked too far into this yet, but will take a look for one soon.

EDIT

Did not find you anything that can work, did find some cool stuff; but my new recommendation is do a quick copy over to word and use words built in function. I did not check the widgets section though, there may be something there.

Comment: may be bookmarklet?

Answer (score 0):

This may be a bit too convoluted for many, but you can do it on an ad-hoc basis with modern browser developer tools.

In Chrome, you can Inspect Element, right-click the element, and "Store as Global Variable" (in Firefox you can do it with "Use in Console").  It will get a name like `temp1`.

Then in the JS console you can do something like:

```
temp1.value = temp1.value.replace(/This/g, "That")
```